# Why is AJAX being called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Solved**: The issue was because the button event was also the submit button, changing it to a `type="button"` solved the issue. Thanks for everyone's help.

I'm making an AJAX call to the server...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".invite-members-submit-btn").one("click", function() {
    alert("alert number one");
    $.post("invite_team_member", {
      token: $("#token").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      team: $("#team").val()
    },"json")
      .done(function (responseText) {
        alert("alert number two");

        $(".invite-result").html(responseText.response);

        alert("alert number three");
      });
  });
});
```

However, whenever I click the invite members button the ajax is called twice. There is no other copies of this ajax call found in my compiled js code and I checked in the back-end server to find that two calls are being made.

To fully understand what's happening, I also made a video showing the error in [action](http://youtu.be/YAgO_1j7slU). My question is why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I saw this once when I was using precompiled assets on my development server, it had built the JS files in the public directory and the result was the files being included twice. Cleaning up the precompiled assets fixed it. Worth checking out! Check the location of the file being executed in the console for both calls to see if it's coming from two separate locations,  check to see if the JS file is being included more than once in your source.

Comment: I ran `rake assets:clean` but still getting the same thing.

Comment: Wait, so `alert("alerts twice");` goes twice, but `alert("third time");` only goes once?

Comment: @squint Sorry, I should be more descriptive in my code. alerts twice only alerts once. The video is thorough and shows exactly what is happening.

Comment: In the video, the form POSTs twice for one click, but only shows the alert number one once, weird...

Comment: Yep. That's why I have SO. :)

Comment: Same behavior in other browsers? And what version of jQuery is it?

Comment: @squint Same effect on Chrome and currently using jQuery v1.9.1.

Comment: Same result using GET?

Comment: @roasted Interesting. It's now sending a get request which is successful then immediately after a POST request which fails since I changed the routes to only accept a get request.